# How should I backup my VMWare virtual machine?

Tags: backup, vmware-player

I am using VMWare Player and I need to transfer my virtual machine to another PC.  Can I just copy everything in the virtual machine's directory to a DVD and restore it on another machine?

Are there any "gotcha's" that I need to be aware of?

I had a look through the VMWare documentation but the answer wasn't evident...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work with no issue, as long as the other system is using a vmware player install as well - the whole purpose of vmware player is to enable things like that.